# MYSQL statement to reindex table from index of 1 again

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a MYSQL statement to re-index every row of a table from the index of 1 again? I don't think there is, but I'm asking just in case. So something like:

```
REINDEX tableName;

index: 2 
index: 5
index: 7
```

^---The above would turn into something like:

```
index: 1
index: 2
index: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific function to do that, you can drop the index column and re-create it. The values would be reassigned.

The query is something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP `index`;
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD `index` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

However, if you want new rows to start from `1`, you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a MYSQL statement to re-index every row

NO.

Because an index is not what you think it is.

Index is not a silly number but an *unique identifier inalienably bound to the record*. And you should never "reindex" anything because it will make the *index* essentially useless.